# getting error while coverting .html file to codeigniter Found 2 elements with non-unique id

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I just changed the extension of a file from `.html` to `.php`.

because I need to us in Codeigniter view.

when in `.html` it shows no warning but when I convert that to .php show warnings

### with **.html**

[image]

### when converted to .php for Codeigniter view

[image]

Found 2 elements with non-unique id come if I add any id any tag.

didn't understand why this happens. I am using Axios request to send data

because of this error didn't get any data because when I add a single id I make then two as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Neither of those errors have anything to do with PHP, so that's not the issue. The jQuery error means the datetimepicker library is not loaded. The `2 elements with non-unique id` means just that: Two elements in your HTML are sharing the same ID. This is against the HTML recommendations.

Comment: basically these warnings come when I convert file from .html to .php

Comment: and I tried to set  unique ids  but  the error displayed

Comment: @ArslanAhmad what do mean by convert

Comment: when I change the extension of .html file to .php

Comment: @ArslanAhmad show us code